# How to get new clients by months in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table `Clients`.

Every client has `da_reg` (date registered in our system). I need to make a report:

By months - total number of clients (`count(distinct customernumber)`); and new customers by `da_reg` date (I can do this per month like insert all clients from past month into temp table and then compare `WHERE da_reg < 'date' and customerid not in (select customerid from #temp)` - however it takes a lot of time to every time compare).

How to make it easiest way? In 1-2 steps?

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try this

```
  select count(*) as new_count,
  month(da_reg) as month,year(da_reg) as year
  (select count(*) from tbl a where tbl.da_reg>=a.da_reg) as total_cus
  from tbl
  group by month(da_reg),year(da_reg)
```

Comment: SELECT MAX(total_cus), sum(new_count), [month], [year]
FROM
(
select count(*) as new_count,
  month(da_reg) as month,year(da_reg) as year, (',' were missing)
  (select count(*) from cee_clients a where cee_clients.da_reg>=a.da_reg) as total_cus
  from cee_clients
where da_reg > '20110101'
  group by month(da_reg),year(da_reg),cee_clients.da_reg) A

GROUP BY [month], [year]
order by month,year

Answer (score 0):

You can Select DAtE_TIME column by month and then calc an number of row :Example for August

```
SELECT *,count(a.id) 
FROM TABLE A as a
WHERE DATEPART(month, MY_DATETIME) = 8
```

where a.id PK of A

Comment: Yep, that works, but what i wanted to know, if there is somehow possible to get with one query answer like this:

Month;Clients;New
jan;1111;11
feb;1112;1
mar;1200;xx

etc